# How can you obtain a sample of changeling?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-ds9, changeling

In the middle of [Paradise Lost](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Paradise_Lost_(episode)) Captain Sisko is framed into allegedly being a changeling. Plot is achieved by presenting a sample of something, that looks like a Sisko's blood, which then turns out to be something like a changeling material.

How can you obtain a piece or sample of changeling? How can you detach a piece out of body? Is *changeling materia* a kind of fluid, that can be extracted? How can it change to anything without connection to a brain that would control transformation abilities and *tell* the sample, what it should change to?

Is this case addressed or explained anywhere in-universe?

Comment: “How can it change to anything without connection to a brain” — *a* brain? Oh you solids, and your quaint conceptions of biology and consciousness.

Comment: With a spoon, I assume?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite All right, not a brain. But, still, I don't buy the idea of self-conscious, self-changing "pieces of changeling" or samples of "raw changeling material". As per my comment to the answer below, I don't believe, that such sample (once extracted with a spoon) would manage to do the show, that Leyton planned.

Comment: @trejder: “ I don't buy the idea of self-conscious, self-changing "pieces of changeling"”. Fair enough. A small sample from a plant can, I believe, often grow into what looks like another complete plant. Perhaps changelings are meant to work like that.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You're right. I forgot the whole [amoeba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amoeba)'s idea, where an entire organism can be reproduced out of a tiny part.

Comment: Why does it have to be changeling blood at all, how closely do humans look when the sample turns. It just has to 'appear' to turn. Extract blood sample then have the hypospray add a chemical that reacts to make it a silver colour (we can do that today with food colouring). I think adding something that changes the colour and viscosity would be easy (it could even be coating the inside of the clear bottle part, or even a gas that filled the bottle before hand), ie its invisible until real blood is added then it reacts and changes the blood (a superficial change is good enough)

Answer (score 2):

Memory Alpha surprisingly seems to cover this [fairly simply](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Blood_screening):

> *When the Changelings threatened Earth in mid-2372, Starfleet Command
>   adopted an official policy, recommended by Benjamin Sisko (acting as
>   temporary head of Starfleet Security on Earth) requiring weekly blood
>   screenings of all Starfleet personnel and their immediate families.
>   (DS9: "Homefront") However, Admiral Leyton managed to fake a blood
>   screening to frame Sisko as a Changeling when Sisko was trying to
>   expose Leyton's attempted coup against the Federation civilian
>   government.*

Leyton possibly already had a sample of changeling blood, and as part of his plan, he swapped out Sisko's blood for this sample. It's likely he had authority to access all areas of the space station including the medical lab, since he was the Admiral.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It, however, answers only half of my question. It answers, how to obtain a sample of changeling. It, surprisingly, does not answer, how that sample managed to change itself into blood and then back into "base material" to do the little tricky show, Leyton planned.